# Getting the sum of field with where conditions with Eloquent

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to get the total sum of downloaded files over all time and the last 24 hours for reporting purposes. The table I'm working on has a `downloaded_at` field which is a `DATETIME` type and a `size` field, which is the file size in bytes. In my model I'm doing the following queries:

```
return array(
    'totalBandwidth' => self::where('downloaded_at', 'IS NOT', DB::raw('null'))->sum('size'),
    'bandwidthLast24Hours' => self::where('downloaded_at', 'IS NOT', DB::raw('null'))->where('downloaded_at', '>' , new DateTime('yesterday'))->sum('size')
);
```

Pretty simple, however both of these queries return `NULL` and I can't figure out why. I've pretty much written these queries based from answers on SO and the Laravel forums.

Comment: Have you missed `->get()` at the end of your queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't check for `IS NOT NULL` like that. You gotta use the `whereNotNull` method. Example:

```
return array(
    'totalBandwidth' => self::whereNotNull('downloaded_at')->sum('size'),
    'bandwidthLast24Hours' => self::whereNotNull('downloaded_at')->where('downloaded_at', '>', new DateTime('yesterday')->sum('size')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Operators usable in the where function are the same of [query builder one's](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2d03b148aaf07766ac0f5bf4a133dc8526f38e3d/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L142) :

```
protected $operators = array(
    '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=',
    'like', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike',
    '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
);
```